# Python if statement not working inside function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a guess the number game in python. However, in the again() function I cannot seem to get the if statement to run.

When I don't use the again function and copy and paste all the code in the respective positions, it works fine. However when I use the again function, the "play again?" question is asked but the if statement is ignored, causing the while loop to continue endlessly. I have tried using the global function but on the second time I input a guess, it comes up with TypeError: 'str' object is not callable .

```
import random

def guess():
    global num
    num = random.randint(1,3)
    guessat  = input("Out of 1 to 3, which number do you guess? ")
    return(guessat)

def again():
    global again
    again = input("Play again? ")
    if again in ["y","yes"]:
        guessing = True
    else:
        guessing = False

print("Welcome to Guess the Number!")

guessing = True

while guessing:
    guessy = guess()
    guessy = int(guessy)
    if guessy == num:
        print("You got it right!")
        again()

    elif guessy != num:
        print("Wrong number!")
        again()
quit()
```

When I input "no" or anything else for the question "Play Again?" I expect the program to exit the while loop and quit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Comment: don't rely on globals, make your function return something.

Comment: Add 'return guessing' in the method 'again()'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if/else statement works perfectly, the problem is elsewhere. More specifically, there are 2 things wrong in your code.

1. the use of the same name `again` for both the variable and the
   function, you should use different names.
2. the `guessing` variable should be global as well otherwise the while-loop will never see it changing.

Try this:

```
def again():
    global guessing
    _again = input("Play again? ")
    if _again in ["y","yes"]:
        guessing = True
    else:
        guessing = False
```

One more thing. As others commented already, the use of global variables is generally not a good idea, is better to have your function return something instead.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid naming your variable `again` inside a function called `again`. However in regards to your infinite loop problem, you set **local** variable `guessing` inside the `again` function, no the **global** variable `guessing`, hence the variable checking the while loop condition is not affected at all.  Might I suggest:

```
def again():
    global guessing
    play_again_input = input("Play again? ")
    if play_again_input in ["y","yes"]:
        guessing = True
    else:
        guessing = False
```